# How to support new ambient mode in android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, ambient

Since last update Android Wear has a new feature - the always-on mode. This means that the Android Wear device doesn’t turn off the screen; it changes to the ambient mode to save battery and keeps certain apps running in the background.

How exactly should I implement this?

p.s. I'm developing sport application, not watchface.

Comment: It would be useful to change the title to have AlwayOn in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is how to support "Ambient Mode" in your Wear app's activity.

There is an entire doc dedicated to this:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html

As well as a code sample:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AlwaysOn/

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed this ;d

Answer (score 1):

We have also created a code lab to run through the steps. Please find it here:

https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/always-on#1