# Android Studio wear: Is there a way to detect when the watch enters and exits ambient mode even if you're not in the app?

Tags: android, mode, ambient

Android Studio wear: Is there a way to detect when the watch enters and exits ambient mode even if you're not in the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606170/how-to-support-new-ambient-mode-in-android-wear. Refer this, may be this helps you

Comment: Unfortunately that only works when the app is open. Thanks though.